# output table to obtain the rows

Tags: ms-access

We want an output table to obtain the rows to simulate

DB:

SampleTable1

```
Name       Product
```

---

```
 Jan         Book
 Smith       Glass
 ....        .....


select * from SampleTable1
```

i would like result This Select Same Below output.

outPut:

```
Row        Name       Product
```

---

```
  1          Jan         Book          
  2          Smith       Glass
  3          ....        .....
```

In Access 2007

Comment: you have tagged mysql, orcle and sql-server-2008. For which you need the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Oracle you can do

```
select rownum as Row, Name, Product
  from SampleTable1;
```

For mySql:

```
select @rownum := @rownum + 1 as Row, Name, Product
  from SampleTable1, (select @rownum := 0)
```

For SQL Server:

```
select row_number() over (order by Name) as Row, Name, Product
  from SampleTable1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, Product, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS Row
  FROM SampleTable1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql i think it would be like this:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 slno, s.* from SampleTable1 s, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```